# Will pandas.read_excel preserve column order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to read a sheet in excel file. But the number of columns(approx 100 to 150), column names and column position may change everyday in the sheet. Will pandas.read_excel return a dataframe with columns in the same order as they are in my daily excel sheet ? I'm using pandas 0.25.3

Comment: You can use [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` will return to you the column order exactly as in the original file. If the order changes in the file, the order of columns in the dataframe will change too.

You can define the column order yourself when reading in the data. Sometimes you'd also load the data, check what columns are present (with `dataframe.columns.values`) and then apply certain heuristic to preprocess them.

Comment: @DarakDir You're welcome. If that answers your question, consider accepting the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: :) Sorry. Was in a bit of hurry. I got my question answered. Accepted the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

It may be late now. I would like to share how I handle reading of Excel files.

I put arguments to `read_excel()` in a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    # Table1 is taken from worksheet 1 in Workbook.xlsx
    'Table1': {
        'workbook' : './Workbook.xlsx',
        'worksheet': 'Sheet1',
        'columns'  : ( # Only need columns in this order
            'Column1',
            'Column3',
            'Column2',
        ),
        'converters': {
            'Column1': lambda x: int(0) if x=='' else int(x),
            'Column2': lambda x: '-' if x=='' else x,
        }
    }

# Read the required data from Excel file
df = pd.read_excel(
    data['workbook'],
    sheet_name=data['worksheet'],
    usecols=data['columns'],
    converters=data[converters]
)

# Sort the order of columns
df = df[data['columns']]
```